# How can i draw a Toggle button with protruding and concave feel when checked and is not checked?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

[image]

the image is the example of toggle. When the toggle button is unchecked, it will be the first one.

When mouse over, the toggle button will be the second one, and when it is checked, it will be the 3th one.

I don't know how to draw the button with protruding feel(2nd) and concave feel (3th) with XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the right place for this kind of question as this site is mainly for programming questions and this is obviously a pure graphical question.
Regarding your question - In Expression Blend there's an option of applying an InnerShadow and outer glow. An outer glow could help you with achieving the second image, and an InnerShadow will help you achieve the 3rd image.

You can read about it in here -

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msmossyblog/archive/2008/09/15/how-to-make-innerglows-with-expression-blend.aspx

Also -

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/innershadows.aspx